# aws lambda: Cannot find module 'string-similarity'

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit

I'm trying to do my first skill for alexa and I'm using aws lambda for logic, my problem is that when I run the test it gives me back:

```
{
  "errorMessage": "Cannot find module 'string-similarity'",
  "errorType": "Error",
  "stackTrace": [
    "Function.Module._load (module.js:474:25)",
    "Module.require (module.js:596:17)",
    "require (internal/module.js:11:18)",
    "Object.<anonymous> (/var/task/index.js:3:24)",
    "Module._compile (module.js:652:30)",
    "Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)",
    "Module.load (module.js:565:32)",
    "tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)",
    "Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)"
  ]
}
```

I need string-similarity to compare two strings but I do not understand how to install it in lambda.

this is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "alexa",
    "skill"
  ],
  "author": "",
  "license": "",
  "dependencies": {
    "ask-sdk": "^2.0.0",
    "string-similarity": "^1.2.0",
    "i18next": "^10.6.0",
    "i18next-sprintf-postprocessor": "^0.2.2"
  }
}
```

and so I call the package in the index.js

```
'use strict';
const Alexa = require('ask-sdk');
var stringSimilarity = require('string-similarity');
...
```

how can i solve this error

thanks for your help and sorry for my english but I'm not a native speaker.

Comment: did you do `npm install`? it's looking for that module in your node_modules directory

Comment: yeah you need to run npm install and then zip your code with it before shipping it to aws lambda if you want full instructions let me know

Comment: In addition to what Dan Oswalt said... after you npm install, according to aws documentation you have to zip node_modules with your application code files. "Then, specify the .zip file name as your deployment package at the time you create your Lambda function."

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error because you are using '**string-similarity**' but you have not installed it in your project that is why it is giving you "errorMessage": "Cannot find module 'string-similarity'".

You **can not add** Node Modules directly in Lambda function. If you need to use external modules/libraries you need to have your project in local machine so you can **npm install** the required modules an then upload the .ZIP file of your project in lambda function see details [**HERE**](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-create-deployment-pkg.html).

Alternatively you can use **ASK CLI** to write your code some editor of your choice and deploy the lambda function with a simple command.